# Specifying dot size in geom_jitter() does not change all the points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to adjust the dot size for my plot using geom_jitter() but it looks like it's adjusting it for some points but not for specific points. Looking through my data, it seems like it's changing the top and bottom points for the column labeled Initial and Final to the right size, but the original large point still remains. I know because I should only have a single point at the high and low outliers.

Here's my code

```
 p_n <- ggplot(n,aes(x=Time,y=n)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(height = 0,width=0.1), size = 0.5) + 
  ylim(1.5,3) +  labs(x = ' ', y='n') + 
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c('Initial','Final')), map_signif_level = TRUE, text_size = 6)
```

Any help is appreciated.

[image: My plot]

Comment: The large dots are outliers being plotted by `geom_boxplot`. Use `geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0.5)` to align those in size with the jitter points (thus duplicating those ones), or use `geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)` to remove them altogether.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you!